# Hibernate @OneToMany / @ManyToOne Column not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am getting a Column Not Found error when trying to call the REST API for my web app using `Spring-Boot`, `Hibernate` and the `CrudRepository` interface.

I have two entities, a News Source and a News Item. The News Source (e.g.: Abc News) has many News Items.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="newsitem")
public class NewsItem

@ManyToOne
private NewsSource newsSource;
```

and

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@Entity
@Table(name="newssource")
public class NewsSource

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "newsSource", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<NewsItem> newsItems;
```

Both my tables are populated correctly as can be verified in my H2 Console.

The relationship annotations added a column in my `NewsItem` table called `Newssource_id`. However, it was not populated automatically. So I added code to assign it when the items are fetched from external API.

```
 public Future<List<NewsItem>> fetchAllNewsItemsFromApi(){
    List<NewsSource> sources = newsSourceDao.fetchAllNewsSources();
    List<NewsItem> newsItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (NewsSource source : sources) {
        String request = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?apikey=" + NEWSAPI_API_KEY + "&source=" + source.getId();
        ResponseEntity<NewsItemResponse> newsItemResponse =
                restTemplate.exchange(request,
                        HttpMethod.GET, null, NewsItemResponse.class);
        NewsItemResponse response = newsItemResponse.getBody();
        List<NewsItem> itemsFromSource = response.getNewsItemList();
        for (NewsItem item : itemsFromSource){
            item.setNewsSource(source);
        }
        newsItems.addAll(itemsFromSource);
    }
    return new AsyncResult<>(newsItems);
}
```

I had to create two additional response classes as the NewsApi JSON returns metadata in addition to just the articles / sources.

```
public class NewsItemResponse {
    @JsonProperty("articles")
    private List<NewsItem> newsItemList;
```

and

```
public class NewsSourceResponse {
    @JsonProperty("sources")
    private List<NewsSource> sourceList;
```

I've set up a NewsItemRepository like so:

```
public interface NewsItemRepository extends CrudRepository<NewsItem, Long>{}
```

And my `http://localhost:8080/api/v1` looks like this:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "newsItems" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/newsItems"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/newsItems` I get a 500 Error.

In browser:

```
could not prepare statement; SQL [select newsitem0_.id as id1_0_, newsitem0_.version as version2_0_, newsitem0_.author as author3_0_, newsitem0_.date as date4_0_, newsitem0_.news_source_id as news_sou9_0_, newsitem0_.summary as summary5_0_, newsitem0_.title as title6_0_, newsitem0_.url as url7_0_, newsitem0_.url_to_image as url_to_i8_0_ from newsitem newsitem0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

In IntelliJ:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "NEWSITEM0_.NEWS_SOURCE_ID" not found; SQL statement:
select newsitem0_.id as id1_0_, newsitem0_.version as version2_0_, newsitem0_.author as author3_0_, newsitem0_.date as date4_0_, newsitem0_.news_source_id as news_sou9_0_, newsitem0_.summary as summary5_0_, newsitem0_.title as title6_0_, newsitem0_.url as url7_0_, newsitem0_.url_to_image as url_to_i8_0_ from newsitem newsitem0_ [42122-191]
```

[image: Sample row from my NewsItem table]

[image: Sample row from my NewsSource table]

[NewsApi.org Api](https://newsapi.org/#apiArticles)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the framework tries to add additional underscore based on the camelcase. This seems to be against the default JPA behaviour, which should only add the underscore between the relationship name and foreign id.

Anyway.. try to explicitly define the join column:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="newssource_id")
private NewsSource newsSource;
```

Comment: This is indeed the case, but do you know why it is happening? Because as soon as I fix it for this column, it fails on another column (e.g. urlToImage --> url_to_image)

Comment: Try to change the name to 'newssource' without the camelcase and remove the `@JoinColumn`, im quite sure there will be only one underscore generated. In my opinion, like i pointed out, this seems to be some sort of a bug to me because that is the violation of the JPA specification which clearly states the behavior in a situation where there is not explicit declaration of a column name

Answer (score 0):

`NEWSITEM0_.NEWS_SOURCE_ID` and Given table's last item `NEWSSOURCE_ID` is different. Make it same.

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed happening, but the question is to why it is setting the column name incorrectly